# Magento 2 - multiple emails sent only over 3 accounts

Tags: magento2, orders, email

Im not sure if this is a bug inside of 2.2, or 2 in general & or if its just related to myself. Because if this is a bug, then i'll open it in github, but if it means I'm doing something stupid then please let me know.

**The issue:**

On adding 3 email addresses to the following:

> Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales emails -> Send Order Email Copy To

I'm receiving 2 copies of the **New order** every time a new order is placed. Obviously this is annoying, but what seems to be strange is, if there is less than 3 inside of the ***Send Order Email Copy To*** then only one copy of the **New order** comes through.

Has anyone else had this issue, or experienced this? Im pretty lost on it. I've checked the email logs on the server and fro some reason its doubled up on everything!

Could it be related to the cron? Could it be related to outside of magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to send emails with *Enabled/Disabled*

**Store > Configration > Sales > Sales Emails > General Settings > Asynchronous sending**

2. In case of Asynchronous sending is **Enabled**, check what you are correct install RabbitMQ http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html)
3. Always check log files.